# Required MultipartFile parameter 'file' is not present in spring mvc

Tags: java, image, spring, spring-mvc, file-upload

I am trying to add feature of uploading picture to my spring mvc application.

jsp part:

```
...
<form method="POST"  action="uploadImage" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <div class="load-line">
                    <input type="file" class="file"/>
                    <input type="submit" value="Upload">
...
```

configuration:

```
... 
<bean id="multipartResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" />
...
```

controller:

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/member/createCompany/uploadImage", method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody String handleFileUpload(
            @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file){
        String name = "image_name";
        if (!file.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                byte[] bytes = file.getBytes();
                BufferedOutputStream stream =
                        new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(new File(name + "-uploaded")));
                stream.write(bytes);
                stream.close();
                return "You successfully uploaded " + name + " into " + name + "-uploaded !";
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return "You failed to upload " + name + " => " + e.getMessage();
            }
        } else {
            return "You failed to upload " + name + " because the file was empty.";
        }
    }
```

After I selected picture I click upload and see error message:

```
HTTP Status 400 - Required MultipartFile parameter 'file' is not present
```

What do I wrong?

Comment: hi can you send me the full code please am facing same problem.naresh.vadlakonda@darkhorseboa.com this is my mail id

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have not specified the `name` attribute , [`@RequestParam("textFile")`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RequestParam.html)  requires name ,

```
 <input type="file" class="file" name="textFile"/>
```

Answer (score 11):

add name attribute to "file" input tag

```
<input type="file" class="file" name="file"/>
```

Comment: Sorry, I shouldn't add name as new RequestParam

Answer (score 2):

For those, who cannot find a suitable solution, please do not forget to add

```
spring.http.multipart.enabled=true
```

to your configuration file

Answer (score 1):

For Springboot:
If your application does not use spring-boot-starter-web and spring-boot-starter-data-rest, instead it uses "spring-boot-starter-webflux", then you will get the error "HTTP Status 400 - Required MultipartFile parameter 'file' is not present" when you use "@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file" in your POST request.

Since webflux is a reactive library, MultipartFile is not supported.

You need to follow this link for reactive-programming way to upload form-data. https://github.com/entzik/reactive-spring-boot-examples/blob/master/src/main/java/com/thekirschners/springbootsamples/reactiveupload/ReactiveUploadResource.java

I have tried a lot. For webflux only application, the above solution alone works.