# Spring Thymeleaf Required request part 'file' is not present

Tags: java, spring, file-upload, thymeleaf

I'm trying to upload big files using Spring and CommonsMultipartResolver (something very similar to [this related topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27101931/required-multipartfile-parameter-file-is-not-present-in-spring-mvc/27101988))

Uploading even a small files (few Kb) results as:

```
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this 
as a fallback.

Fri Mar 02 23:54:59 MSK 2018
There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
Required request part 'file' is not present
```

Here is my UploadController.java "/upload" method code:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/upload", consumes = 
MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public String singleFileUpload(@RequestParam("file") 
MultipartFile file,
                        RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes){

    if (file.isEmpty()){
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("message", "Файл для загрузки не выбран. Выберите файл в диалоге");
        return "redirect:/files";
    }

    try {

        BufferedOutputStream outputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(
                new FileOutputStream(
                        new File(UPLOAD_LOCATION + "\\", 
file.getOriginalFilename())));
        outputStream.write(file.getBytes());
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();

String.format("Файл %s успешно загружен", file.getOriginalFilename()));

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return "redirect:/files";

}
```

my form code:

```html
<div class="form-group">
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/upload">
<input type="file" class="file" name="file" />
<small id="fileHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Выберите файл для загрузки в файловый каталог приложения. После загрузки файл автоматически появится в этом списке. </small>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Загрузить на сервер</button>
</form>
</div>
```

and the annotation bean definition:

```
@Bean
public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() { CommonsMultipartResolver 
multipartResolver = new CommonsMultipartResolver();
multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(10 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024); // 10 GB
multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSizePerFile(3 * 1024 * 1024 * 1024); // 3 GB
return multipartResolver;
}
```

and application.properties:

```
spring.http.multipart.max-file-size=3000MB
spring.http.multipart.max-request-size=3000MB
```

I have a correct attribute name "file" at form input and `@RequestParam` value, also I wrote a MediaType at `@PostMapping` annotation, but it still fails to work.
Also, i've noticed, that when I'm not defining CommonsMultipartResolver bean, the upload works, but only with files less than 300 Mb...

What do I do wrong?

Comment: problem is still unsolved... could anyone help?

Comment: same issue, have you find a solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the following property to your .properties file:

```
multipart.enabled=true
```